# How do I switch inline div elements uing angularjs? ng-switch or ng-hde or ng-show?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I simply need to switch div orientation based on some type of event. It could be onclick, ng-switch, ng-show, ng-hide. Please show me one that works. I don't want to use ng-include.

```
   <body ng-app="mdoApp"ng-init="getValue='1'">
    <label>type a number(1 to 3):
    <input type="text" ng-model="getValue" />
    </label>
    <div class="div_contain1" ng-switch="getValue">
    <span ng-switch-when="1"ng-hide=""><div class="div_p2">PART 3</div>
    <div class="div_p2">  PART 2</div><div class="div_p1"> PART 1</div></span>
    <span ng-switch-when="2" ng-hide=""><div class="div_p2">PART 3</div>
    <div class="div_p1"> PART 2</div><div class="div_p1"> PART 1</div></span>
    <span ng-switch-when="3" ng-hide=""><div class="div_p1">PART 3</div>
    <div class="div_p1"> PART 2</div><div class="div_p1"> PART 1</div></span>
    <span ng-switch-default="1"><div class="div_p2">PART 3</div>
    <div class="div_p2"> PART 2</div><div class="div_p1"> PART 1</div></span>
    </div>
```

Ok, what I want to do is switch out  div panels when a form is submitted. Preferably during an on click event when form data is submitted. Each part represents a new form or questionare. Hence the user will be informed when they complete a section of the registration, by seeing at the top a graphical representation of them moving to the next Part of the registration. hence, Part 1, Part 2, Part 3.

Ok,this is another attempt at manipulating div layers:

```
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
   <head>

<title>Untitled 31</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
       </head>
    <body>
   <div ng-app="showApp" ng-init="showDiv='1'">
  <div ng-controller="showView">
  <label>type a number(1 to 3):
  <input type="text" ng-controller ="showView" ng-model="showDiv" />
  </label>
   <div ng-show="divA">con1</div>
   <div ng-show="divB">con2</div>
   <div ng-show="divC">con3</div>
   </div></div><p></p> 
   <script>
   var app = angular.module('showApp', []);
   app.controller('showView', function(showDiv, $scope){
   return{
   If (showDiv === 1){
    $scope.divA = true;
    $scope.divB = false;
    $scope.divC = false;  
   }   
   If (showDiv === 2){
   $scope.divA = false;
   $scope.divB = true;
    $scope.divC = false;
  }   
  If (showDiv === 3){
   $scope.divA = false;
   $scope.divB = false;
   $scope.divC = true;
   }  
   }
   });
   </script>

   </body>
    </html> `
```

Answer (score 0):

> "switch div orientation"

I am not sure what you mean by this. But you should know what each of the events are you are talking about:

onclick 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

ng-switch 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

ng-show 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

ng-hide 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Once you define more clearly the orientation you want, the better you can solve this problem. For example, if you want a div to show up when a scope variable is on, then ng-show is every easy to use. If you need more to happen when a click is executed, you can call a function using ng-click very easily. I can make a fiddle if you define your goal more.

Comment: Ok, what I want to do is switch out  div panels when a form is submitted. Preferably during an on click event when form data is submitted. Each part represents a new form or questionare. Hecnce the user will be informed when they complete a section of the registration, by seeing at the top a graphical representation of them moving to the next Part of the registration. hence, Part 1, Part 2, Part 3.

Comment: Also, why switching divs is important is because I want to be able to load all my div panels into a js file so that the user can click through all panels client side, making the app more efficient. I am hoping to use json file also, to capture MySQL data for quick perusing. This app actually has 6 spa since each are independent of the other and some use a template that is portrait and others use a landscape template. hence my work is  mounting since I originally thought I could do this with PHP and ajax, but Angularjs is far more appropriate.

Comment: Well yes. You can do this with simple CSS and PHP too - if you have your data loaded, you could theoretically display: none the items you don't want to have seen. And javascript out the events to make it work. But you are right, angular is easier, and separates concerns. I would go with a simple ng-hide on every div and setup variables for the different states. If you set $scope.divA = false in your js then ng-show="divA" on your html will not show up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/8Yz7S/4/
This will show you more how ng-hide and ng-show work. You can easily do what you are looking for. Your ng-click can be useful whenever you want these variables changed.

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I'm not sure, yet. I am going to upload another strip of code. Maybe you can show me the error in my logic. because I can't get it to work in any of the browsers. I am still new to angular so I haven't grasped the logical flow of the programing language yet. see code above.

Comment: The fiddle I posted should give you what you need. Pay attention to 
ng-click="showCon('con1')
and ng-show="clickOn=='con1'"
in the html and 
$scope.clickOn=con; inside the function that is called every time on click. You will see only the div set by the function will show up. That is all you need to hide and show divs. Even simpler is if you only need a toggle, then your ng-show could point to a boolean instead of a function. Let me know if that helps explain it more.

Comment: Also, if you are new, you definitely want to read up as much as you can on scope and directives. These two items can lead you far down the road to learning all you need to know in angular. Once you have those down, read up on Services. They are like bridges between your scopes.